# react-chartjs-2: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID '' can be reused

Tags: reactjs, typescript, charts, chart.js

So I am trying to create a pie chart with a json data of:

```json
{
  "Desktop": 28,
  "Mobile": 36,
  "null": 11
}
```

Here's a full preview of my code requesting to an api with json json file response, this is also a component graph:

```
            const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME}/api/analytics/getAnalyticsByDateNoType`, fetchData);
            const response_data = await response.json();
            
            //Select the nested array/object inside the response
            const analytics = await response_data.data.users[0].analytics;

            //Count the same value in Device Column of analytics
            const device_counts = await analytics.reduce((counts: { [x: string]: any; }, item: { device: string | number; }) => {
                counts[item.device] = (counts[item.device] || 0) + 1;
                return counts;
            }, {})

            //Sample output of 'device_counts' is:
            //{
            //   "Desktop": 28,
            //   "Mobile": 36,
            //   "null": 11
            //}

            const processedData = {
                labels: Object.keys(device_counts),
                datasets: [{
                    data: Object.values(device_counts),
                    backgroundColor: Array(Object.keys(device_counts).length).fill('#FF6384'),
                    hoverBackgroundColor: Array(Object.keys(device_counts).length).fill('#36A2EB')
                }]
            };

            setProcessedChartData(processedData)
```

and i printing it with:

```
 <Pie data={processedChartData} />
```

I am getting two errors from this

- Error 1, Error: "arc" is not a registered element.
- Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID '' can be reused.

I am using version of Chart.JS

- `"react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",`

I was expecting to print a pie chart with a data of

```json
{
  "Desktop": 28,
  "Mobile": 36,
  "null": 11
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial method that I have tried must be outdated so I visited chart.js template from new issue page [react-chartjs-2 sandbox (React)](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/62344860/211868858-7421b700-2a3c-427e-a75f-70e953c40a7e.png)

I used this method instead of the code I have provided in this post:

**Imports**

```
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';
import { Chart as ReactChartJs } from 'react-chartjs-2';
```

**Chart**

```
<ReactChartJs type="pie" data={processedChartData} />
```

**[View Output](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/62344860/211868858-7421b700-2a3c-427e-a75f-70e953c40a7e.png)**

Comment: Make sure to call the register function: "Chart.register(...registerables);"